# Shared library pipe shown as could not be found in vscode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-pipe, angular-library, angular-language-service

I added a new shared library with a pipe ( `RemoveUnderscorePipe` ). I'm using the library an angular app. The app using the library compiles and works fine. The issue is that in vs-code there are errors in all templates using the pipe:
[image]

This makes the developer experience less enjoyable, and go to definition on pipe name does not work either.

I found a similar question:
[Unable to resolve signature for pipe invocation in vscode by Angular Language Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701385/unable-to-resolve-signature-for-pipe-invocation-in-vscode-by-angular-language-se)
And have tried the suggested solution without success.

How can I make the vscode recognize the library. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Angular extension, make sure the library is correctly added in `angular.json`. Otherwise, try to reset VSCode few times - I remember it took me at least 3 resets for VSCode to "wake up"

Comment: The question might look stupid but have you imported the pipe's module correctly?

Comment: The application compiles and works correctly. The only issue is in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

So, in Early August 2020 vs code angular language services need to be restarted after library is built. And the library must be built with --prod flag.
Found answer here:
https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/645#issuecomment-587282612

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by not using a default export for my pipe.

Instead of

```
export default class PricePipe implements PipeTransform {}
```

Do

```
export class PricePipe implements PipeTransform {
```